# Is there a smart way to pick up Page Design other than Template to Design mapping?

Tags: sxa

I would like to choose Page Designs to my pages not by mapping their Template to certain Page Design. I would like e.g.: to change page design when a certain field is empty.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! SXA 1.9 has a new feature called Design rules. You will find a new field on the Page Designs item:

[image]

where you can design a rule which will pick up Page Design for you thanks to new "select specified page design" action. Here is an example rule:

[image]

So right now we have two fields where you can select Page Design and the priority is a fallow:

1. If Page Design is specified on a page itself it will always win
2. If there is no Page Design explicitly assigned on the page SXA will try to resolve "Design rules" and pick Page Design out of it
3. If we don't have rules or none of the rules will be evaluated we will fall back to good old "Template to Design Mapping" field